# MySQL double sort

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I would like to double sort my user list. Is this possible within one MySQL query?

1. Sort by `activity`
2. Sort by `ID`

For example:

```
1  Jack   Active 
2  Jill   Active 
5  Jens   Active  
3  Harry  Inactive 
4  Larry  Inactive 
6  Luke   Inactive
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `ORDER BY` clause to sort as many columns as needed.

```
SELECT id, name, activity
FROM userList
ORDER BY Activity, ID
```

I would suggest reading the MySQL `ORDER BY` docs. You can sort the data either in `ASC` or `DESC` order: [MySQL: ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT id, name, activity
FROM your_table
ORDER BY activity ASC, id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from table order by activity, ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY activity, ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes,

```
SELECT (user.name|| ' ' || user.status) AS sorted_list
FROM STUDENTS
ORDER BY user.status, user.name
```

Comment: i think you missed `FROM user`